# how to simplify and solve this equation :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, absolute-value

> Solve this equation for $x$:
>
> $$\left|x \sqrt{1-x^2} +x \right| = \sqrt{1+x^2}$$

I'm having a problem getting rid of the square root!

Comment: Use LaTeX to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided $-1\le x\le 1$, you get:

\begin{align}
\left|x \sqrt{1-x^2} +x \right| = \sqrt{1+x^2}\\
\left|x \left(\sqrt{1-x^2} +1\right) \right| = \sqrt{1+x^2}\\
|x|\left(\sqrt{1-x^2} +1\right)  = \sqrt{1+x^2}\\
x^2\left(\sqrt{1-x^2} +1\right)^2  = 1+x^2\\
x^2\left(1-x^2+2\sqrt{1-x^2}+1\right) = 1+x^2\\
2x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}=x^4-x^2+1\\
4x^4\left(1-x^2\right)=\left(x^4-x^2+1\right)^2
\end{align}